# How to create a MYSQL scheduled event from Monday to Friday at specific time?

Tags: mysql, events, schedule, dayofweek

I have this code:

```
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2015-11-20 23:00:00'
DO
UPDATE users SET username='verde' WHERE id=1;
```

Help, my code update users every day at 23:00, but I want only to update users from monday to fridays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the logic found here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

```
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2015-11-20 23:00:00'
DO
  IF DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 THEN
  UPDATE users SET username='verde' WHERE id=1;
  END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer help me a lot. Finally I achieved it doing this

CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2015-11-23 10:50:00'
DO
        UPDATE users 
        SET username=  IF( DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) BETWEEN 2 AND 6, 'verde',username)         WHERE id=1;